# I can't find out where segmentation error(core dumped) was occured. Please give a newbie a hand

Tags: c

I want to make multiprocessing program with executing time to compare the number of process with executing time.
the details are here:
first I made makerand.c that makes 5000000 random numbers and write on random.txt file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define NUM_VALUES 5000000
#define FILENAME "random.txt"

int main() {
    FILE* file = fopen(FILENAME, "w");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("파일을 열 수 없습니다.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    srand(time(NULL));  // 시드 설정

    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_VALUES; i++) {
        int randomValue = rand();
        fprintf(file, "%d\n", randomValue);
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

I think there is no problem in makerand.c because I can get random.txt after executing makerand.c

Second I made bucketsort.c that read random.txt and do bucketsorting while going through the list I made that contains the number of process(nunique = 13)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_NUM 5000000 // 최대 데이터 크기
#define BUCKET_SIZE 100 // 버킷 크기
#define FILENAME "random.txt"
#define OUTPUT_FILENAME "sorted.txt"

void bucketSort(int arr[], int n) {
    int max_val = arr[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] > max_val) {
            max_val = arr[i];
        }
    }

    int num_buckets = (max_val / BUCKET_SIZE) + 1;
    int** buckets = (int**)malloc(num_buckets * sizeof(int*));

    for (int i = 0; i < num_buckets; i++) {
        buckets[i] = (int*)malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    }

    int* bucket_sizes = (int*)calloc(num_buckets, sizeof(int));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int bucket_idx = arr[i] / BUCKET_SIZE;
        buckets[bucket_idx][bucket_sizes[bucket_idx]] = arr[i];
        bucket_sizes[bucket_idx]++;
    }

    int index = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_buckets; i++) {
        if (bucket_sizes[i] > 0) {
            for (int j = 0; j < bucket_sizes[i]; j++) {
                arr[index] = buckets[i][j];
                index++;
            }
        }
        free(buckets[i]);
    }
    free(buckets);
    free(bucket_sizes);
}

int main() {
    FILE* file = fopen(FILENAME, "r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("파일을 열 수 없습니다.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    int arr[MAX_NUM]; // 데이터를 저장할 배열
    int num = 0; // 데이터의 개수

    while (fscanf(file, "%d", &arr[num]) != EOF) {
        num++;
    }

    fclose(file);

    int num_processes_list[] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 10, 20, 40, 70}; // 프로세스 수 목록

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(num_processes_list) / sizeof(num_processes_list[0]); i++) {
        int num_processes = num_processes_list[i];

        // 각 프로세스에 할당할 데이터 크기
        int chunk_size = num / num_processes;
        int start = 0;

        clock_t start_time = clock();

        for (int j = 0; j < num_processes; j++) {
            if (j == num_processes - 1) {
                // 마지막 프로세스는 나머지 데이터를 처리
                chunk_size = num - start;
            }

            pid_t child_pid = fork();

            if (child_pid == 0) {
                // 자식 프로세스는 일부 데이터를 정렬
                bucketSort(&arr[start], chunk_size);
                exit(0);
            } else if (child_pid < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "프로세스 생성 실패\n");
                exit(1);
            }

            start += chunk_size;
        }

        // 모든 자식 프로세스가 종료될 때까지 대기
        int status;
        for (int j = 0; j < num_processes; j++) {
            wait(&status);
        }

        clock_t end_time = clock();
        double execution_time = (double)(end_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

        printf("프로세스 수: %d, 실행 시간: %.6f 초\n", num_processes, execution_time);

        // 정렬된 데이터를 파일에 저장하거나 출력
        FILE* output_file = fopen(OUTPUT_FILENAME, "w");
        if (output_file == NULL) {
            printf("결과 파일을 생성할 수 없습니다.\n");
            return 1;
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < num; j++) {
            fprintf(output_file, "%d\n", arr[j]);
        }

        fclose(output_file);
    }

        return 0;
}
```

when I run bucketsort.c the segmentation error occurs.
I don't know how to find where the wrong code is so I finally come to stack over flow.. Please help me

I want to know the solution I have talked upon. please give me a help

Comment: First problem is probably `int arr[MAX_NUM];` - allocating 20 MB on the stack in one go doesn't work for... reasons. You can try with a smaller size first, move the variable outside the function into global scope or turn that into a malloc.

Comment: I think you intend to do the work by chunks done by children spawned by fork? That won't work, the child inherits the parent's memory, but any changes to variables done in the child do not propagate back to the parent. You would have to use something like shared memory to do that.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is `int arr[MAX_NUM];`. That's an immediate stack overflow for `MAX_NUM=5000000`. You're trying to allocate ~20 MiB of stack space. On Windows, the default stack size is only 1 MiB.

To help debug issues like this, you can compile your code with [`-fsanitize=address`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-fsanitize_003daddress) enabled (GCC or Clang). In this case, it produces the tell-tale diagnostic:

```
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-overflow /app/example.cpp:51 in main
```

where `example.cpp:51` is the line `main` is defined.

Comment: thank you for your help. But when I adjust MAX_NUM less than 25000, The Problem occurs again... Is there anything I should do? I'm trying to find out the way to use -fsanitize=address now but i really need help

Comment: @seokkyu It's entirely possible that there's more than one memory issue in your program.  Adjusting `MAX_NUM` at least allows your program to enter `main` and reach the first `if` for me. To continue debugging, you can try enabling warnings and using a debugger. See [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/11082165) and [Why should I always enable compiler warnings?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57842756/11082165)

Comment: Also note that `arr` may need to be much smaller than 1 MiB, since the stack space is shared by everything. That includes all local variables, function arguments, return addresses, etc. You program can't exceed the stack limit at any point. So setting `MAX_NUM` to a large (but barely small enough) value may just delay the stack overflow. You can avoid that by making `arr` a global variable or by dynamically allocating memory for it.

Comment: thank you for your help. I am trying to solve it